# Getting an input as an int for a list

Tags: python, vector, casting, calc

I'm trying to have the user input a vector so that it can be added, subtracted, etc. The first line is the list input, but it is storing all of the characters as strings including the brackets and commas. The third and fourth line gets rid of the brackets and commas, leaving the three user-inputted numbers as strings.

```
v = input('Input integers for a vector "v" ex. [1,2,-7]: ')

aux = v[1:-1]
list = aux.split(',')

for x in list:
    int(x)

print(list[0] + list[1])
```

The for loop is my attempt to iterate the list and make all of the numbers into integers but it is still returning them as strings. For example, if I input the list [3,6,5], the program will print 36 at the end instead of the intended 9. I tried using the map function to change them, but that was returning the same values as strings.

How can I make all of the list items into integers after removing the brackets and commas?

Comment: You don't assign `int(x)` to anything

Comment: *All those `int(x)` will be lost in loop, like unassigned references in Python*

Answer (score 0):

First of all the int() caster does not cast the variable in place, it returns the casted value so you need to assign it back.

Secondly, when using the loop of the kind

```
for x in list:
```

x is not a pointer reference to the list element, instead it is variable with the value of the list element copied into it, so even if you did:

```
for x in list:
    x = int(x)
```

the elements in the list will not be affected.
Your loop to convert string chars to int should be (one approach):

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i] = int(list[i])
```